Calculating NDVI using OrfeoToolbox
Platform: Windows 11
Aim trying to achieve: I have downloaded some multispectral test data from OpenDroneMap (ODM) forum. The data is captured with DJI Mavic 3M. What I want is to analyze NDVI, NDRE, NDWI, EVI (if possible), and other soil and water related classifications. Currently I am focusing on NDVI.
Steps taken: First I created an orthomosaic with all the multispectral TIFs (one single orthomosaic), which consists of 3 bands: Red (band-1), Green (band-2) and NIR (gray, band-3). Then I tried to calculate the NDVI with Orfeo Toolbox cmd-line (I don't wish to use the QGIS plug-in).
I ran the following command for calculating NDVI:
otbcli_BandMath -il odm_orthophoto.original.tif -out NDVI.tif float -exp "((im1b3 - im1b1) / (im1b3 + im1b1))"

I got an output, but it was a just grey tif file with 1 band: gray (normalized -1 to 1).
Then I went to the documentation of Orfeo Toolbox and looked under the "RadiometricIndices" section, from where I got the following example command:
otbcli_RadiometricIndices -in odm_orthophoto.original.tif -list Vegetation:NDVI -out RadiometricIndicesImage.tif -channels.red 1 -channels.green 2 -channels.nir 3

Still, I got the same output; grey tif file with just 1 band: gray (normalized -1 to 1).
My Orthomosaic:

My Output (NDVI):


What are you expecting as output? NDVI is a ratio between red and NIR resulting in a single raster bounding -1 to 1. That sounds like what you are getting.

Display your data with a  pseudo color color ramp.  Maybe green for 1 and red for -1.  https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/training_manual/rasters/changing_symbology.html

Leverage the MATLAB hyperspectral imaging library to estimate NDVI and various other spectral indices, either through the spectralIndices function or the Hyperspectral viewer app."

So, you are providing a commercial software solution for an open access software question? Seems like a bit of a non sequitur. Good recommendation pointing out a valuable resource but, should have been provided as a comment and not an answer. Besides, "link only" answers are a bit frowned upon here.
